# How can I format number shown in HTML to currency format, including the $ symbol and placing decimals with <sup></sup>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with several HTML text strings with numbers, let's say one is 123.20. All of them are enclosed at third level in a div with the "money" class. I want to change all of them to the format $123<sup>.20</sup> (the number is different for each of them) using JS.

I cannot include the "money" class to the any other div than the first shown below. I cannot format this into the backend (even if I would love to).

I don't know where to start from.

This is an example of the current HTML.

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-11138f85 elementor-widget__width-auto money elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="11138f85" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix">123.20</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I would need to get displayed:

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-11138f85 elementor-widget__width-auto money elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="11138f85" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix">$123<sup>.20</sup></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where are your values coming from?

Comment: So in JS I would take text and split it at `.`, then second part wrap in `<sup>`, put back to HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample using `split()`

```
// find all the elements with your `money` class
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('money')

// loop through all the `money` elements
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  // split the money value into two parts (before the decimal and after)
  var amounts = elements[i].innerHTML.split('.')

  // update the content to your formatted version
  elements[i].innerHTML = amounts[0] + '<sup>.' + amounts[1] + '</sup>'
}
```

Comment: add a dot (.) before amounts[1]

Answer (score 2):

[Intl​.Number​Format - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

```
var number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('tr-TR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'TRY' }).format(number));
```

**Output**

```
₺123.456,79
```

Answer (score 0):

for Euros:

```
var number = 1500;

let numCurrency = new Intl.NumberFormat('eu-EU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number);

console.log(numCurrency);
```

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat